# Azure Search how to make highlight response shorter using odata query syntax?

Tags: azure, odata, azure-cognitive-search

i am working with Azure Cognitive Search and this is my `odata` query expression:

```
...docs/?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview&search="budget+plan"|"business+plan"&queryType=simple&searchMode=all&$top=20&$skip=0&highlight=merged_content
```

And this is response:

```
4" :
{
    "@search.score" :
        0.20703253,
    "@search.highlights" :
    {
        "merged_content" :
        [
            "0" : "... 1500 characters here! Highlight is on the end ...."
        ]
    },

},
```

And my response from `merged_content` contains lines of couple thousands of chars. My question is, how to `limit` the chars number in response of `Azure Search` using `odata query syntax` and still get highlighted text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have no control over the OData query syntax for what is hit highlighted other than your search query.
See docs below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-pagination-page-layout#hit-highlighting

However, you can implement some client-side logic to only return the highlighted tags since the hit highlights are in `<em>` tags.